# How to set maxline for text?

Tags: flutter, dart

[flutter ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGLDP.jpg)

I tried to make it fit the screen. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Please add your overflow area code. Maybe you can solve that problem by using Expanded widget and Text widget's overflow parameter.

Comment: use maxLines properties in text widget - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html

Answer (score 0):

you can set the text's `overflow` variable like this:

```
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue using the `Expanded` Widget. Wrap your overflowing text widget with the `Expanded` Widget.

Sample code:

```
const Expanded(
   child: Text('i dont know 55555555555555555555555555555555'),
),
```